# Installation candidate for AD join not found

Tags: apt, package-management, active-directory

I'm trying to rebuilt a server wich is part in the Active Directory. I'm using Bionic Beaver:

```
administrator@vmssnt1:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
administrator@vmssnt1:~$ uname -a
Linux vmssnt1 4.15.0-32-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 10 17:58:07 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Of course I did `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` before I executed

`sudo apt -y install realmd sssd sssd-tools libnss-sss libpam-sss adcli samba-common-bin oddjob oddjob-mkhomedir packagekit` by following this guide: https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_18.04&p=realmd

This worked when I did it on other servers before, but now I only get this error:

```
Package realmd is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package adcli is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'realmd' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'adcli' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package oddjob
E: Unable to locate package oddjob-mkhomedir
```

If I'm looking at The packages I can find them (for example realmd: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/realmd)

Is there anything that I'm missing?

Thanks for your help!

---

**EDIT:** If I use `apt-cache search realmd`on my ubuntu windows subsystem (14.04.5 LTS) The package can be found. Is there no more support for bionic beaver?

Comment: Check out what packages installed on https://www.turnkeylinux.org/domain-controller .  It's running debian Jessie, but a dpkg --list should let you see what someone has working OOTB.

Comment: @RobotHumans thx. Will have a look, if no one has an answer. As I said I already did an installation with these packages...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked for me:

Add the following the end of /etc/apt/sources.list

```
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
```

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install realmd

Comment: sudo apt-get update

Comment: thanks, that was it. Strange that I did this setup many times and universe was added automaticly.